# Memory management dilemma, Objective -C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have been testing different features of Objective -C and reached topic which deals with memory management. Apparently upon reading few documents it seems memory management is a very strict in order to build well functioned application.

Now as per my understanding, When we allocate a memory an object's `retainCount` will become **1**. However Something I wrote for learning purposes and it is giving me abnormal `retainCount`

It might be abnormal number for me, But people who's knows under the hood, Could you please explain how did I get this `retainCount` and what will be the best way to release it.

Code which has abnormal retainCount,

Object name is : `...(UISlider *) greenSender...`

```
-(IBAction) changeGreen:(UISlider *)greenSender{
    showHere.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red.value green:greenSender.value blue:blue.value alpha:1.0];
    NSLog(@"retainCount %d",[greenSender retainCount]);
}
```

Has `reatainCount`, just after executing my code.

[image]

A short explanation will give me a hint, And external reading resources would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Green sender is coming from somewhere else.  To figure out where your retain counter is coming from we need the rest of the uses of that pointer.

Comment: Sorry my bad it's just a UISlider, parameter passed into a method, It's 1:27AM in melbourne...Apologise.

Comment: If I had to guess I would say greenSender is part of your UI, so UI components will have references to your object, thus a retain count of 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Do not rely on retain counts**.  They should only be used as a debugging tool.  The reason is that if an object gets `retain`ed and `autorelease`d, its *effective* retain count has not changed, but its *actual* retain count has increased by one.  It will be `release`d at some point in the future when the autorelease pool drains.  Therefore, you cannot rely on the retain count for knowing whether the object has been managed properly or not.

A large retain count such as 8 may indicate a programming bug (such as retaining it too many times), but it could also just be a sign that it has been `retain`ed and `autorelease`d a large number of times, which, although curious, could be perfectly valid.

Comment: Sometimes somethings seems so useful but poor programmers, I would probably use my own brain to count how many time I passed or retained any particular object :), Thanks

Comment: You don't really want to count this stuff yourself either... it's not going to help you debug anything. It's better to track down bugs by making sure you've conformed to the memory management conventions. Check out NSZombies and Instruments if you need a tool to help debug memory issues.

Comment: Thanks Chris, Let me google those zombies, It's very weird experience to program in Obj-C straight after java.

Answer (score 5):

**Do not** trust/rely on `retainCount`. Really.

From Apple:

> **Important**: This method is typically of no value in debugging
>   memory management issues. Because any number of framework objects may
>   have retained an object in order to hold references to it, while at
>   the same time autorelease pools may be holding any number of deferred
>   releases on an object, it is very unlikely that you can get useful
>   information from this method.

Comment: Thats quite interesting, Thanks Jilouc however 1+ for effort but I have to accept Adam's answer as he said it first, Thanks

Comment: @krio No problem, Adam was too fast :)